# How can I Iterate through all possible unique pairs using elements from a set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, python-itertools

I'd normally write:

```
for i in range(len(collection)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(collection)):
        print(collection[i], collection[j])
```

That relies on the elements being ordered. How can it be done when using an unordered collection?

Comment: Set is not indexable

Comment: I am unsure of what you are trying to accomplish, but with collection being unordered but iterable, you could do `result=set([(x, y) for x in collection for y in collection])`

Comment: @DeaXStormZ That would include things like `(x,x)` where the 2 elements are the same.

Comment: are these 'unique pairs': (1,2),(...), (2,1) or are they seen as duplicated?

Comment: I’m aware sets are not indexable, as I said, that’s what I’d do with an ordered (therefore indexable) collection. The code was to better illustrate what I’d like to do.

Comment: (1,2)…(2,1) are duplicated. The code illustrates this

Comment: This is a good question, except the last sentence confuses me. What did you mean "relies on the elements being ordered"? Did you mean indexed? Or iterated multiple times?

Comment: I meant indexed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```py
import itertools as it

result = it.combinations(collection, 2)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!